# Why do we get saturation current in photoelectric effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect

So apparently if you increase the number of photons emitted per second to infinity, the photocurrent will approach a limiting value called the 'saturation current'

I feel like we shouldn't get a saturation current because as one electron is emitted, another will immediately (or close to immediately) fill its place just like in a normal current - thus electrons can pretty much be continuously emitted.

Can anyone explain why we get saturation current? Thanks :D

Comment: The problem is the space charge that gets produced by the cloud of electrons that accumulates above the metal surface. To get rid of it we have to apply an electric field, but that is ultimately limited because the electrons that will be accelerated by that field will have to hit a collection electrode, where they will cause the release of secondary electrons and may also release photons of their own. If we make this electric field too strong then the current in the device starts multiplying even without any external light. This is a dynamic range-limiting problem in photomultiplier tubes.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your opening statement?  I am used to "saturation current" referring to saturation with increasing voltage and fixed intensity, not saturation with increasing intensity.

Comment: 'Close to immediately' isn't immediately, either.

Comment: @BowlOfRed No unfortunately, it's just from my school physics teacher, but I'm wondering if anyone knows what exactly will happen if we increase intensity - does it approach a limiting current? Thanks

Comment: See graph 1 on this page: http://resource2.rockyview.ab.ca/physics30_BU/Unit_C/m6/p30_m6_l02_p2.html

Comment: Thanks @BowlOfRed, the test is tomorrow HAHA hmm might show him this in the morning.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, if you could explain how that relates to 'saturation current' that would be helpful!